# how to sort a dict list into a single list with many lists inside it and within each single list all the sorted dicts?

Tags: json, python-3.x

how to sort a dict list into a single list with many lists inside it and within each single list all the sorted dicts?

Example

```
[
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Egnatia",
      "Away": "Kukesi",
      "Times": "19.03. 15:00",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Egnatia",
      "Away": "Kukesi",
      "Times": "20.03. 16:09",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 41",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Lincoln",
      "Away": "Leyton Orient",
      "Times": "19.03. 16:00",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 30",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Napoli",
      "Away": "Atalanta",
      "Times": "30.03. 12:30",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024"
    }
  }
]
```

I expect an output like this:

```
{
  "Giornata 29": {
    "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024": [
      {
        "Day": "Giornata 29",
        "Matches": {
          "Home": "Egnatia",
          "Away": "Kukesi",
          "Times": "19.03. 15:00",
          "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
        }
      },
      {
        "Day": "Giornata 29",
        "Matches": {
          "Home": "Egnatia",
          "Away": "Kukesi",
          "Times": "19.03. 15:00",
          "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Giornata 41": {
    "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024": [
      {
        "Day": "Giornata 41",
        "Matches": {
          "Home": "Lincoln",
          "Away": "Leyton Orient",
          "Times": "19.03. 16:00",
          "Championship": "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Giornata 30": {
    "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024": [
      {
        "Day": "Giornata 30",
        "Matches": {
          "Home": "Napoli",
          "Away": "Atalanta",
          "Times": "30.03. 12:30",
          "Championship": "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect many lists sorted by "Day" and "Championship", how can this be done in the simplest way possible?

Comment: I am a little confused because you ask for "a single list with many lists inside it", but your example output is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results in a sorted manner, then you might want to sort your input data as a first step. Since dictionaries preserve insertion order you should be able to preserve your sort order when constructing you result.

I personally prefer `setdefault()` to `defaultdict()` but they very similar things in the end.

You can [read more about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) `dict.setdefault()`

```py
data_in = [
    {"Day": "Giornata 29", "Matches": {"Home": "Egnatia", "Away": "Kukesi", "Times": "19.03. 15:00", "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"}},
    {"Day": "Giornata 29", "Matches": {"Home": "Egnatia", "Away": "Kukesi", "Times": "20.03. 16:09", "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"}},
    {"Day": "Giornata 41", "Matches": {"Home": "Lincoln", "Away": "Leyton Orient", "Times": "19.03. 16:00", "Championship": "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024"}},
    {"Day": "Giornata 30", "Matches": {"Home": "Napoli", "Away": "Atalanta", "Times": "30.03. 12:30", "Championship": "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024"}}
]

## ---------------------
## pre-sort the rows based on day|chamionship|time
## sort() orders the rows in place updating data_in as it does so.
## in this case, the order is specified by the tuple (Day, Championship, Time)
## ---------------------
data_in.sort(key=lambda row: (row["Day"], row["Matches"]["Championship"], row["Matches"]["Times"]))
## ---------------------

data_out = {}
for item in data_in:
    matches = item["Matches"]

    ## ---------------------
    ## value = some_dictionary.setdefult(key, default_value)
    ## Will set some_dictionary[key] = default_value if key is not in some_dictionary.
    ## it will set value to some_dictionary[key]
    ## ---------------------
    data_out \
        .setdefault(item["Day"], {}) \
        .setdefault(matches["Championship"], []) \
        .append(dict(
            (k,v)
            for k,v
            in matches.items()
            if k in ["Home", "Away", "Times"]
        ))

    ## -----------------
    ## An equivalent version of the above that might be easier
    ## to follow is:
    ## -----------------
    """
    target = data_out
    target = target.setdefault(item["Day"], {})
    target = target.setdefault(matches["Championship"], [])
    target.append({
        "Home": matches["Home"],
        "Away": matches["Away"],
        "Times": matches["Times"],
    })
    """
    ## -----------------

import json
print(json.dumps(data_out, indent=4))
```

Giving you:

```
{
    "Giornata 29": {
        "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024": [
            {
                "Home": "Egnatia",
                "Away": "Kukesi",
                "Times": "19.03. 15:00"
            },
            {
                "Home": "Egnatia",
                "Away": "Kukesi",
                "Times": "20.03. 16:09"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Giornata 30": {
        "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024": [
            {
                "Home": "Napoli",
                "Away": "Atalanta",
                "Times": "30.03. 12:30"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Giornata 41": {
        "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024": [
            {
                "Home": "Lincoln",
                "Away": "Leyton Orient",
                "Times": "19.03. 16:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer I was looking for is correct in your second solution, could you kindly comment the code? if there is documentation regarding the features you use to learn? I'm new to python, thanks a lot friend! ❤️

Comment: in addition to the code, I would like to understand if there is documentation regarding the functions you use in the code.

Comment: "if k in ["Home", "Away", "Times"]" I would like to understand this function

Comment: `k` is the keys of the "matches: dictionary. So that condition builds a new dictionary out of matches with just those three keys in it.

Comment: yes it is clear, but you specify "if k (in)" so you would specify if there are values in the keys, at least that's how I understand it, is that correct?

Comment: Here `k` is a dictionary key like "Home" or "Championship" and we are saying that we are only interested in those keys `k` when they are found in the list `["Home", "Away", "Times"]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you input data is in a variable named `data`, you could do this (with the caveat noted in my comment on your question -- this produces the sample output you *show*, not what you *describe* in the beginning of the question):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = ...

sorted_data = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    sorted_data[item["Day"]].append(item)
```

If you want the inner list sorted by `...["Matches"]["Championship"]`, you could do this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import insort


sorted_data = defaultdict(list)
for item in data::
    insort(sorted_data[item["Day"]], item, key=lambda x: x["Matches"]["Championship"])
```

Comment: This is close, but the current result is a two level dictionary based on Day and Championship.

Comment: How can I manipulate them? I tried as if it were a normal dict but I get an error...

Comment: They are just normal python data structures.